# Is there any way to make the output in SQLPlus wider(on Windows )?

Tags: cmd, sqlplus

In an attempt to more easily view the output in SQLPlus, I fiddled with window-size properties and font(tiniest font).

But this is what I get :

[image]

It is exactly the same, just much less readable.

I just want to run the query :

```
select * from user_tables where rownum < 10 ;
```

Without the messy unreadable lines (currently I can't tell apart the data from table headings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [one useful SQL*Plus option](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#i2678481) and [one additional helper option](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#i2683480) it is possible. Put

```
set linesize 32767
set trimout on
```

before your select.

Enjoy.